# How to merge two sorted arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, sorting

Consider the following tow sorted arrays:

```
let arr1 = [1, 7, 17, 25, 38]
let arr2 = [2, 5, 17, 29, 31]
```

simply, the expected result should be:

```
[1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17, 25, 29, 31, 38]
```

In fact, if we tried to do a simple research for this issue, we will find many resources provide the following "typical" approach:

```
func mergedArrays(_ array1: [Int], _ array2: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var result = [Int]()
    var i = 0
    var j = 0

    while i < array1.count && j < array2.count {
        if array1[i] < array2[j] {
            result.append(array1[i])
            i += 1
        } else {
            result.append(array2[j])
            j += 1
        }
    }

    while i < array1.count {
        result.append(array1[i])
        i += 1
    }

    while j < array2.count {
        result.append(array2[j])
        j += 1
    }

    return result
}
```

therefore:

```
let merged = mergedArrays(arr1, arr2) // [1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17, 25, 29, 31, 38]
```

which is perfectly workable.

**However, my question is:**

What would it be if we tried to achieve it with more "Swifty" shorthanded solution?

*Note* that doing it as:

```
let merged = Array(arr1 + arr2).sorted()
```

would not be so clever, because it should be done as `O(n)`.

Comment: `sorted` is **std lib** sort which is optimum

Comment: This old question is very misguided.  (aa + bb).sorted() is **mathematically the best you can do performance wise** unless special conditions are pre-existing.  (Which is meaningless, because, compsci 101, you'd have to .. check those exist anyway.)  If this was an **actual performance question** (for some sort of obscure scientific processing case, where you assume certain conditions) it's utterly inconceivable you'd use Swift.  If, triply-bizarrely, you for some reason "had to" use Swift,  it's (aa + bb).sorted().

Answer (score 13):

I tried to solve your problem in **Functional Programming** and **without variables**.

Given 2 arrays

```
let nums0 = [1, 7, 17, 25, 38]
let nums1 = [2, 5, 17, 29, 31]
```

We concatenate the first one with the **reversed** version of the second one

```
let all = nums0 + nums1.reversed()
```

The result will be:

```
[1, 7, 17, 25, 38, 31, 29, 17, 5, 2]
```

### Theory

Now if we pick, one by one, the minimum element we have at the edges (left or right), we are guaranteed to pick all the elements in ascending order.

```
[1, 7, 17, 25, 38, 31, 29, 17, 5, 2] -> we pick 1 (left edge)
[7, 17, 25, 38, 31, 29, 17, 5, 2] -> we pick 2 (right edge)
[7, 17, 25, 38, 31, 29, 17, 5] -> we pick 5 (right edge)
[7, 17, 25, 38, 31, 29, 17] -> we pick 7 (left edge)
[17, 25, 38, 31, 29, 17] -> we pick 17 (right edge)
[17, 25, 38, 31, 29] -> we pick 17 (left edge)
[25, 38, 31, 29] -> we pick 25 (left edge)
[38, 31, 29] -> we pick 29 (right edge)
[38, 31] -> we pick 31 (right edge)
[38] -> we pick 38 (both edges)
```

Now let's have a look at the array we have built picking all these elements.

```
We selected 1: [1]
We selected 2: [1, 2]
We selected 5: [1, 2, 5]
We selected 7: [1, 2, 5, 7]
We selected 17: [1, 2, 5, 7, 17]
We selected 17: [1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17]
We selected 25: [1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17, 25]
We selected 29: [1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17, 25, 29]
We selected 31: [1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17, 25, 29, 31]
We selected 38: [1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17, 25, 29, 31, 38]
```

This looks like the result we want to achieve right?

Now it's time to write some Swifty code.

### Code!

[image]
Ok, how can we do this in Functional Programming?

Here's the code

```
let merged = all.reduce((all, [Int]())) { (result, elm) -> ([Int], [Int]) in
    
    let input = result.0
    let output = result.1

    let first = input.first!
    let last = input.last!
    // I know these ☝️ force unwraps are scary but input will never be empty

    if first < last {
        return (Array(input.dropFirst()), output + [first])
    } else {
        return (Array(input.dropLast()), output + [last])
    }
    
}.1
```

### How does it work?

**1.**
We pass to the reduce a tuple containing the `all` array and an empty array.

```
all.reduce((all, [Int]()))
```

> We will call first array `input` and the second one `output`.
> Step by step the reduce will remove the minimum element from the edges of `input` will append it to `output`.

**2.** Then, inside the closure, we give proper names to the 2 elements of out tuple

```
let input = result.0
let output = result.1
```

**3.** We select the first and last element of input

```
let first = input.first!
let last = input.last!
```

> Yeah, I don't like force unwraps either but since `input` will never be empty, these force unwraps will never produce a fatal error.

**4.** Now if `first < last` we need to:

- return the input minus the first elemewnt
- return output + the first element of input

Otherwise we do the opposite.

```
if first < last {
    return (Array(input.dropFirst()), output + [first])
} else {
    return (Array(input.dropLast()), output + [last])
}
```

**5.** Finally we select the second element of the tuple returned by reduce since it's where our result is stored.

```
}.1
```

### Time complexity

<s>Computation Time is O(n + m) where n is nums0.count and m is nums1.count because:</s>

```
nums1.reversed()
```

This ☝️ is **O(1)**

```
all.reduce(...) { ... }
```

This ☝️ is **O(n + m)** since the closure is executed for each element of `all`

Time complexity is O(n) ^ 2. Please see valuable comments below from *@dfri*.

### Version 2

This version should really have O(n) time complexity.

```
let merged = all.reduce(into: (all, [Int]())) { (result, elm) in
    let first = result.0.first!
    let last = result.0.last!

    if first < last {
        result.0.removeFirst()
        result.1.append(first)
    } else {
        result.0.removeLast()
        result.1.append(last)
    }
}.1
```

Comment: It's nice with another approach, but as you mention (asymptotic) time complexity, it should be noted that the repeated array instantiation, copying and appending in the `reduce` closure can be quite expensive. In the computation of `O(n+m)` you implicitly define the _basic operation_ of your asymptotic analysis as one single cover of the closure (of `reduce`), but each such pass contains instantiation of two _new_ arrays: one of the size of `input` and one the size of `output`, as well as possibly copying these (might be elided) as the `return`. This cost will be substantial (times `m +n`).

Comment: ... If we were non-rigorously describe the basic operation of our time complexity analysis as _"viewing and performing operations on a member of the `all` array **or** copying such a member"_, then the time complexity would be `O(n^2)` rather than `O(n)`, as for each `reduce` iteration we twice copy(/instantiate) an array that is, on average, of size `(n+m)/2`.

Comment: @dfri Very good observation. I'm actually afraid the time is even worse. The closure needs to copy 2 arrays (input and output) and the sum of their length is always n+m. So the total time is O(n+m)^2. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Imo, `O(n)^2` and `O(m+n)^2` is the same - I would even consider the latter a (common) mis-use of Big-O notation. We can without loss of generality assume `n > m`, and thereafter perform our asymptotic analysis for an input array of size `2n`, in which case `2` is just a constant and will have no effect on asymptotic growth in terms of Big-O analysis (as we omit any constants from the final notation: e.g., not writing (`O(3n)` but just `O(n)`). So summa summarum: I would consider the time complexity as `O(n)^2`, due to the copying.

Comment: Happy to discuss! Maybe one could make use `reduce(into:)` to circumvent the copying while keeping the same logic as above: I think this "pyramid" approach is great for educational purposes :)

Comment: @dfri I added a `Version 2` using `reduce(into:)` as you suggested. Does it sound right to you? I think we now have `O(n)` time and space.

Comment: `Version 2` does indeed correct the overhead present in the first version. I was first unsure if there could be any issues, however, of passing and mutating `self` (`all`; mutated with `removeFirst()` and `removeLast()`) as (part of) an `inout` variable to a method that [iterates over elements of `self`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/9d2b582d897b5c89931aa19bd2856d034db70496/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L649), but I realized the initial `(all, [Int]())` tuple contains a copy of `all` for the following mutation, so no issue there :) nice!

Comment: With all respect, and I'm sorry to say, this would be the worst algorithm I have ever seen on SO ("and that's saying something"). It is a stunning combination of inelegance, "completely pointless novelty", total disregard for performance principles, epic lack of knowledge of the specific details of the programming milieu at hand, and has no didactic value as novelties sometimes do.  Amazing.

Comment: {Not that it even matters but regarding the addendum, removeFirst() is incredibly slow.}

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you mean by "more 'Swifty'", but here goes.

I would write the function like the following. It's not shorter, but much more generic: you can merge any two `Sequence`s, as long as they have the same `Element` type and `Element` is `Comparable`:

```
/// Merges two sequences into one where the elements are ordered according to `Comparable`.
///
/// - Precondition: the input sequences must be sorted according to `Comparable`.
func merged<S1, S2>(_ left: S1, _ right: S2) -> [S1.Element]
    where S1: Sequence, S2: Sequence, S1.Element == S2.Element, S1.Element: Comparable
{
    var leftIterator = left.makeIterator()
    var rightIterator = right.makeIterator()

    var merged: [S1.Element] = []
    merged.reserveCapacity(left.underestimatedCount + right.underestimatedCount)

    var leftElement = leftIterator.next()
    var rightElement = rightIterator.next()
    loop: while true {
        switch (leftElement, rightElement) {
        case (let l?, let r?) where l <= r:
            merged.append(l)
            leftElement = leftIterator.next()
        case (let l?, nil):
            merged.append(l)
            leftElement = leftIterator.next()
        case (_, let r?):
            merged.append(r)
            rightElement = rightIterator.next()
        case (nil, nil):
            break loop
        }
    }
    return merged
}
```

Another interesting enhancement would be to make the sequence lazy, i.e. define a `MergedSequence` and accompanying iterator struct that stores the base sequences and produces the next element on demand. This would be similar to what many functions in the standard library do, e.g. `zip` or `Sequence.joined`. (If you don't want to define a new type, you can also return an `AnySequence<S1.Element>`.)

Comment: `let prevTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
print(merged(arr1, arr2))
let nowTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
print("Difference--",nowTime - prevTime)//0.00197887420654297` . `let prev = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
print(addedArray.sorted { $0 < $1 })
let now = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
print("Difference--",now - prev)`//Gives 0.000524044036865234 . Added array is arr1+arr2

Answer (score 2):

### Simple Functional Solution

I really love the functional approach introduced by [Luca Angeletti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407789/2062785). The idea with the pyramid is nice as well, but for my taste the code is not readable / intuitive enough, due to the use of the `reduce` function in combination with tuples of arrays. Furthermore, the pyramid concept needs extra explanation for other developers.

Thus, I tried to use [my original idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407007/2062785) with slowly "chopping off" the two arrays from the front and make it **purely functional**. The result is astonishingly simple:

```
/// Merges two sorted arrays into a single sorted array in ascending order.
///
/// - Precondition: This function assumes that both input parameters `orderedArray1` and 
///                 `orderedArray2` are already sorted using the predicate `<`.
func mergeOrdered<T: Comparable>(orderedArray1: [T], orderedArray2: [T]) -> [T] {

    guard let first = orderedArray1.first else {
        return orderedArray2
    }

    guard let second = orderedArray2.first else {
        return orderedArray1
    }

    if first < second {
        return [first] + mergeOrdered(orderedArray1: Array(orderedArray1.dropFirst()),
                                      orderedArray2: orderedArray2)
    } else {
        return [second] + mergeOrdered(orderedArray1: orderedArray1,
                                       orderedArray2: Array(orderedArray2.dropFirst()))
    }
}
```

I would claim that it's a lot easier to read than the other algorithms suggested on this page so far and from my judgement it's even *swifty*!

(It should be noted though that `dfri`'s concern mentioned in the comments to [Luca Angeletti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407789/2062785) also applies here: A new array is instantiated in each recursion step which might be computationally expensive – but it the total number of array instantiations will always be *< m + n – 1*, where *m* and *n* are the number of elements in the arrays to be sorted.)

---

### Thinking further...

This solution could be extended to work with

- any sorting predicates
- generic sequences rather than just arrays as suggested by [Ole Begemann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51405983/2062785)

---

### Benchmark Test

ℹ️ Of all these methods, **the Swift standard sort algorithm is the fastest**. I tested the runtime for all approaches with these two arrays:

```
let first  = Array(1...9999)
let second = Array(5...500)
```

Results:

- Iterator sort (as introduced by [Ole Begemann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51405983/2062785)):
  **37.110 s**
- Functional sort (as introduced in this answer):
  **6.081 s**
- Loop sort (as introduced in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407007/2062785)):
  **0.695 s**
- Swift standard sort (`(first + second).sorted()`)
  **0.013 s**

Of course, it always depends on the particular arrays that you want to merge but from these results I would claim, that actually using **`(first + second).sorted()` is the swiftiest and fastest thing you can do!**

Comment: Would you mind to share the benchmark code? The result is a bit suspicious - I noticed that code executed in playgrounds suffers huge penalty in playground code what would explain slow times for what you tested. Can this be the case?

My tests are showing quite comparable times if I run them as a command line tool (not playground)

Comment: @simpleone , it's completely self-evident that the (bizarre, absurd) algorithms proposed, are wildly slower (in any language) than the (extremely well know) fastest approach

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your definition either, but you might interpret this as swiftier:

```
func mergeOrdered<T: Comparable>(orderedArray1: [T], orderedArray2: [T]) -> [T] {

    // Create mutable copies of the ordered arrays:
    var array1 = orderedArray1
    var array2 = orderedArray2

    // The merged array that we'll fill up:
    var mergedArray: [T] = []

    while !array1.isEmpty {

        guard !array2.isEmpty else {
            // there is no more item in array2,
            // so we can just add the remaining elements from array1:
            mergedArray += array1
            return mergedArray
        }

        var nextValue: T
        if array1.first! < array2.first! {
            nextValue = array1.first!
            array1.removeFirst()
        } else {
            nextValue = array2.first!
            array2.removeFirst()
        }
        mergedArray.append(nextValue)
    }

    // Add the remaining elements from array2 if any:
    return mergedArray + array2
}
```

Then:

```
let merged = mergeOrdered(orderedArray1: arr1, orderedArray2: arr2)
print(merged) // prints [1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17, 25, 29, 31, 38]
```

It's a similar idea and not so much shorter in code but what's "swiftier" in my opinion is that you don't need to keep track of two indices this way.

While this and your implementation gives you O(n), it's a little unsafe because it assumes that both input arrays are already sorted. One might easily oversee this precondition. Thus, I personally still prefer

```
let merged = (arr1 + arr2).sorted()
```

but of course, it depends on the use case.

Comment: `array1.removeFirst()` and `array2.removeFirst()` are both `O(n)` operations.

Comment: *"While this and your implementation gives you O(n), it's a little unsafe because it assumes that both input arrays are already sorted"* That is exactly equivalent to saying "it is nowhere near O(n)".  As you then state (a+b).sorted() is (trivially, obviously) the only code you would ever use.

Answer (score 1):

Citing [@OleBegemann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51405983/4573247)

> Another interesting enhancement would be to make the sequence lazy,
>   i.e. define a `MergedSequence` and accompanying iterator struct that
>   stores the base sequences and produces the next element on demand.

If we would like to use some "more Swifty" approach, and also would like to achieve a lazy interleaved sequence of the interleaved (based on a `<` predicate for element-wise comparison) rather than, as in your example, an array, we can make use of [`sequence(state:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2011998-sequence) and a helper `enum`, and re-use some of the left/right `switch` logic from Ole Begemann's answer:

```
enum QueuedElement {
    case none
    case left(Int)
    case right(Int)
}

var lazyInterleavedSeq = sequence(
    state: (queued: QueuedElement.none,
            leftIterator: arr1.makeIterator(),
            rightIterator: arr2.makeIterator()),
    next: { state -> Int? in
        let leftElement: Int?
        if case .left(let l) = state.queued { leftElement = l }
        else { leftElement = state.leftIterator.next() }

        let rightElement: Int?
        if case .right(let r) = state.queued { rightElement = r }
        else { rightElement = state.rightIterator.next() }

        switch (leftElement, rightElement) {
        case (let l?, let r?) where l <= r:
            state.queued = .right(r)
            return l
        case (let l?, nil):
            state.queued = .none
            return l
        case (let l, let r?):
            state.queued = l.map { .left($0) } ?? .none
            return r
        case (_, nil):
            return nil
        }
})
```

Which we may consume e.g. for logging:

```
for num in lazyInterleavedSeq { print(num) }
/* 1
   2
   5
   7
   17
   17
   25
   29
   31
   38 */
```

Or to construct an immutable array:

```
let interleaved = Array(lazyInterleavedSeq)
// [1, 2, 5, 7, 17, 17, 25, 29, 31, 38]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my bit... this is Sequence protocol extension and a generic function allowing to merge two sequences of the same type (protocol extension) or even ANY two sequences with the same `Element` type.

```
import Cocoa

struct MergeState<T> {
    var lastA: T?
    var iterA: AnyIterator<T>
    var lastB: T?
    var iterB: AnyIterator<T>

    mutating func consumeA() -> T? {
        let aux = lastA
        lastA = nil
        return aux ?? iterA.next()
    }

    mutating func consumeB() -> T? {
        let aux = lastB
        lastB = nil
        return aux ?? iterB.next()
    }
}

extension Sequence where Element: Comparable {
    func createMergeState(with other: Self) -> MergeState<Element> {
        let iterA = AnyIterator(self.makeIterator())
        let iterB = AnyIterator(other.makeIterator())
        return MergeState(lastA: nil, iterA: iterA, lastB: nil, iterB: iterB)
    }

    func mergeSequence(with other: Self) -> UnfoldSequence<Element, MergeState<Element>> {
        let state = createMergeState(with: other)
        return sequence(state: state) { (state) -> Element? in
            guard let valueA = state.consumeA() else {
                return state.consumeB()
            }
            guard let valueB = state.consumeB() else {
                return valueA
            }
            if valueA < valueB {
                state.lastB = valueB
                return valueA
            } else {
                state.lastA = valueA
                return valueB
            }
        }
    }
}

func mergeSequence<S1: Sequence, S2: Sequence>(_ seq1: S1, _ seq2: S2) -> UnfoldSequence<S1.Element, MergeState<S1.Element>> where S1.Element == S2.Element, S1.Element: Comparable {
    return AnySequence(seq1).mergeSequence(with: AnySequence(seq2))
}

let a = [1, 9, 15, 55, 101]
let b = [2, 4, 6, 8]

//merge sequences of the same type
for i in a.mergeSequence(with: b) {
    print("\(i)")
}

let c: IndexSet = [3, 9, 60]

print("---")

//merge any two sequences with the same Element
for i in mergeSequence(c, a) {
    print("\(i)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1. The very obvious "swifty" way to write an interleave:

Purely *as an example of Swift*

```
r = []
for a in aa {
    while let n = bb.first, n < a {
        r.append(bb.removeFirst())
    }
    r.append(a)
}
r += bb
print(r)
```

You would never do that.

(If, incredibly, you had to do that, and there were millions of items, you ***of course would NOT aim for "swiftyness"***, the entire point of which is fast-to-write code that is ***not meant to be efficient***. You'd just, obviously, create an empty array of the fixed known size and then walk two pointers along with one line of (ugly) code.)

### 2. The question is very misguided.

(aa + bb).sorted() is mathematically the best you can do performance wise unless special conditions are pre-existing. (Which is meaningless, because, compsci 101, you'd have to ... check those exist anyway.) If this was an actual performance question (for some sort of obscure scientific processing case, where you assume certain conditions, are unconcerned about crashes etc, there is a vast amount of data, perhaps streaming, etc etc) it is inconceivable you'd use Swift. If, triply-bizarrely, you for some reason "had to" use Swift, it's (aa + bb).sorted().